# Linking a website account to a facebook account so the user can post from the website anytime

Tags: facebook

I'm using the javascript API to link a website account to a users facebook account but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the best/easiest way.

- I've created a facebook app
- Used the FB.ui feed option to allow the user to post to their timeline

This works fine but the ui will ask the user to login each time they start a new session on the website. Have I missed something? Do I need to store and use the User Access Token?

Comment: Yes, you need to store and use the user access token. You'll also need to exchange it for a long-lived token server-side via the Graph API, as the JS SDK gives you ones that expire in a matter of hours.

Comment: actually, for FB.ui feed you don´t even need to authorize the user...

Comment: if they aren't logged into FB though wouldn't my website need to log them in using the user access token to prevent the FB.ui login prompt?

Comment: @Amos You can't log the user into Facebook. If you use FB.ui and they're not logged in on Facebook, they will get a login prompt. That bit's entirely out of your control.

Comment: so is the user access token like a session id by which I can keep the user logged in?

Comment: @Amos Sort of, yes. You can use it to call the Graph API on behalf of the user, so it serves as a credential of sorts. The ones generated by the JS SDK are short-lived (I believe two hours). You can exchange them server-side for one valid for two months if you need to make ongoing calls on behalf of the user.